# We say "person responsible", so would we also say "site responsible"?

Tags: word-order

A responsible person is someone who acts in a responsible manner, and the person responsible is the person whose job it is to deal with something.
What if I want to say that a particular company site or location is responsible for something? Would it be "site responsible", or is "responsible site" more natural in this case? 
This is for the title of a field in a form, so there's no other text before or after "site responsible".
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by site? Site meaning location cannot be responsible, a company can be responsible. You could then refer to the company as: _the responsible company_ or _the company responsible for..._

Comment: [identify the site responsible](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22identify+the+site+responsible%22) That's an estimated 96 written instances, but I think every one of them is followed by a "for-clause" (***for*** whatever the site bears the responsibility of causing or dealing with).

Comment: @FumbleFingers [it's more prevalent in books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=site+responsible%2Cresponsible+site&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csite%20responsible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresponsible%20site%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: 'Departmental responsibility' is commonly expressed and I assume that a 'site' is a 'department' of a company.

Comment: @JJJ: Most of the matches to your NGrams are irrelevant collocations, but [this search of Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22identify+the+site+responsible%22+-%22the+site+responsible+for%22) shows that whereas there were 96 instances of the sequence in my first comment, there are ***none at all*** once I exclude instances where the very next word is ***for***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
I think the question focuses on "site responsible" vs "responsible site", the "identify" you mention isn't mentioned in OP's question.  As stated in the last sentence of the question, it's just those two words on a form.

Comment: @JJJ: I included extra words in my search to minimize "accidental collocations". Google Books claimed 96 hits for what I would call the "natural" adjective position *if the word **responsible** is further qualified with a **for-** clause* (and I then showed that in every one of those 96 cases, there is in fact such a clause immediately following). On the other hand, it claims only 2 instances of [*identify the responsible site*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22identify+the+responsible+site%22), neither of which I can read in context.

Comment: With "site" I'm trying to describe a separate part or branch of the company. For example, the headquarters are in one country, but the company has "sites" (for example, manufacturing facilities) in lots of other countries. Maybe "facility" would be better. Each facility is responsible for certain processes and procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the following from the question into account:

> This is for the title of a field in a form, so there's no other text before or after "site responsible".

I would go with **site responsible** over *responsible site*. The reason for my choice is that the first cannot be read as: *site that acted responsibly*, whereas the second might be read in that way.

The same goes with person, *responsible person* might be read as *a person who is responsible*, whereas *person responsible* is read as *the person who is / was responsible for*.

I should state that this is how I read it, should anyone read it differently, please indicate in the comments.

I would refer to [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_DET_+site+responsible%2C+_DET_+responsible+site&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_DET_%20site%20responsible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20responsible%20site%3B%2Cc0), which indicates *(article) site responsible* is also more prevalent than *(article) responsible site*.

Comment: I think the argument that there's no room for confusion with "site responsible" is a good one.  I'll use that (or perhaps "facility responsible").  Thanks! Also to the other commentators.